# Decrement the count with the click of button using previous state

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [{ name: "Zuko", count: 1 }],
  };

  handle = () => {
    this.setState((prev) => {
      console.log(prev.data[0].count);
      return {
        ...prev,
        count: prev.data[0].count - 1,
      };
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <p>{this.state.data[0].count}</p>
        <button onClick={this.handle}>Click</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @durgesh, welcome to stack overflow. Make sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specificaly: "**Write a title that summarizes the specific problem**" , "**Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague**", and "**Introduce the problem before you post any code**". Also, the tag **react-functional-component** is irrelevent as this question is about a class component.

Answer (score 0):

This part is not correct:

```
    return {
        ...prev,
        count:prev.data[0].count-1
    };
```

It should be something like:

```
    return {
        data: [ {
            ...prev.data[0],
            count: prev.data[0].count - 1,
        },
            ...prev.data.slice(1),
        ],
    };
```

This of course only works for the first item in `data`.